# React-Leaflet v4 with Next.js 13 Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-leaflet

I expirence an issue after updating my Next.js version from 12 to 13 - that also means I updated React from 17 to 18 and react-leaflet from 3 to 4. I have this component:
`

```
function ChangeView({ center }) {
    const map = useMap();
    map.setView(center);
    return null;
}
const createClusterCustomIcon = function (cluster) {
    return L.divIcon({
    html: \`<span>${cluster.getChildCount()}</span>\`,
    className: \`${styles.markerClusterCustom}\`,
    iconSize: L.point(40, 40, true),
  });
};

 const RegularMap = ({ center, organizations, cat, org, orgIcon }) => {
const [organization, setOrganization] = useState();
if(center[0] || center [1] !== null  && center.length > 0 ){
    return (
        <MapContainer center={center} zoom={6} className={styles.mapContainer} scrollWheelZoom={true}
                      style={organizations ? {height: 600, width: "100%"} : {height: 400, width: "100%"}} >
            <ChangeView center={center} />
            <TileLayer
                attribution="© <a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/'>Mapbox</a> © <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a></strong>"
                url="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/freala/ckqtm5ajl6cxr19n2r67a821q/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZnJlYWxhIiwiYSI6ImNrcXRtZHR4djA4Nmkyd3F1ZmM2eHBiYnoifQ.uKDqGDSzf88It8iCuX6fJg"
            />
            {org ? <Marker icon={orgIcon ? icon({
                iconUrl: orgIcon,
                iconSize: [32, 32],
            }) : ICON} position={center}> </Marker> : <Marker icon={ICON} position={center}> </Marker>}
            <MarkerClusterGroup  showCoverageOnHover={false}
                                 spiderfyDistanceMultiplier={2} iconCreateFunction={createClusterCustomIcon}>
            {organizations && organizations.length > 0 ? (
                <>
                    {organizations.map( o => {
                        if(o.latitude && o.longitude){
                            let id = o.id;
                            return(
                                <Marker key={o.id} icon={o.icon ? icon({
                                    iconUrl: o.icon.url,
                                    iconSize: [32, 32],
                                }) : ICON} position={[o.latitude, o.longitude]}
                                       >
                                        <Popup>
                                            <h2 className={styles.popupH2}>{o.name}</h2>
                                            <div style={{width:'100%',display:'flex',justifyContent:'center',margin:'5px 0'}}>
                                                <Link href={{ pathname: o.is_organization ? "/organization" : "/location", query: { id: o.id } }}>
                                                    <a  className="details-org">Szczegóły</a>
                                                </Link>
                                                <style jsx>
                                                    {
                                                        \`
                                                          .details-org{
                                                            padding:10px 20px;
                                                            background-color:#517c92;
                                                            color:white !important;
                                                            border-radius:5px;
                                                            text-decoration:none;
                                                          }
                                                          .details-org:hover{
                                                            color:white !important;
                                                          }
                                                        \`
                                                    }
                                                </style>
                                            </div>
                                        </Popup>
                                </Marker>
                            )
                        }
                    })}
                </>
            ) : null}
            </MarkerClusterGroup>
        </MapContainer>
    )
} else return null
};
```

Here are my depencendcies:
`"dependencies": { "@changey/react-leaflet-markercluster": "^4.0.0-rc1", "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36", "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4", "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4", "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16", "ally.js": "^1.4.1", "bootstrap": "^5.1.3", "easy-peasy": "^5.0.4", "i18next": "^21.5.2", "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2", "i18next-http-backend": "^1.3.1", "leaflet": "^1.9.4", "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility": "^0.1.1", "leaflet-map-server-component": "^0.2.0", "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3", "moment": "^2.29.4", "next": "^13.4.8", "next-share": "^0.22.1", "nprogress": "^0.2.0", "react": "^18.2.0", "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0", "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.2", "react-calendar": "^3.7.0", "react-confirm-alert": "^2.8.0", "react-datepicker": "^4.15.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0", "react-hook-form": "^7.29.0", "react-i18next": "^11.14.2", "react-leaflet": "^3.2.5", "react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1", "react-player": "^2.9.0", "react-select": "^5.3.2", "react-slick": "^0.29.0", "sass": "^1.43.4", "sharp": "^0.32.1", "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1", "swr": "^2.2.0" }`

I tried downgrading the leaflet back to v3 but that just breaks too since it's not compatible with React v18. I can't seem to find anyone who has fixed this problem and when I find someone then it's a different problem that has nothing to do with the version updates and is at least 2 years old. Before the update everything seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using the package "react-leaflet-cluster"(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-cluster) instead of @changey/react-leaflet-markercluster, I was facing the same issue as you. So I decided to go with below package and surprisingly it worked fine with my old code just has to change import statement, you may have to update your code as per docs of this package.

```
import MarkerClusterGroup from "react-leaflet-cluster";
```